# Algebra/arithmetic incorrect equation subtraction

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In this subtraction below, how do the numerators work out to become $1, 1, -2$? I have tried subtracting different terms from the two equations and rearranging too, and nothing comes out to their answer. My final result has consistently been $\frac{5}{3(y^2-9)}+\frac{9}{4(y^2-25)}-\frac{26}{11(y^2-49)}.$ Yet I put it in Wolfram Alpha and the answers are ugly, which one wouldn't expect if it were simply a difference in apperance. What did they do to get that, after "subtracting the above equations"?

[image: BMT 2018 Algebra #9]

Comment: It might be helpful to post the whole problem.